# What is wrong with my code while trying to calculate if the point "point" is in the triangle or not?

Tags: c++, graphics, glsl

Can anybody see what is wrong with my code?

```
float intersect(Ray ray, Triangle triangle) {
    float scalar = (0 - dot(triangle.normal, ray.origin)) / dot(triangle.normal, ray.dir);
    vec3 point = ray.origin + scalar * ray.dir;
```

Berrycentric coordinates

```
    vec3 A = vec3(1, 0, 0);
    vec3 B = vec3(0, 1, 0);
    vec3 C = vec3(0, 0, 1);
```

Using the Berrycentric coordinates
to calculate tby
matrix*tby = [A-point] ==> 
tby = inverse(matrix)*[A-point]

```
    mat3 matrix = mat3(point, A - B, A - C);
    vec3 tby = transpose(matrix) * vec3(A - point);

    float t = tby.x;
    float beta = tby.y;
    float gamma = tby.z;
    if (beta + gamma < 1 && beta > 0 && gamma > 0 && t > 0)
        return scalar;
    return -1.0;
}
```

What I created so far
TriangleStruct

```
    struct Triangle
    {
     vec3 p1;
     vec3 p2;
     vec3 p3;
     vec3 normal;
     Material material;
    };
```

The points

```
    vec3 p1 = vec3(-0.3,0.2,0.5);
    vec3 p2 = vec3(0.3,0.2,0.5);
    vec3 p3 = vec3(0.15,0.0,0.0);
    vec3 p4 = vec3(0.15,0.2,0.5);
```

The triangles

```
    {
```

Triangle 1

```
    scene.triangles[0].p1 = p1;
    scene.triangles[0].p2 = p4;
    scene.triangles[0].p3 = p3;
    scene.triangles[0].normal = normalize(cross((p4-p1), (p3-p1)));
```

Triangle 2

```
    scene.triangles[1].p1 = p3;
    scene.triangles[1].p2 = p2;
    scene.triangles[1].p3 = p1;
    scene.triangles[1].normal = normalize(cross((p2-p3), (p1-p3)));
```

Triangle 3

```
    scene.triangles[2].p1 =p3;
    scene.triangles[2].p2 = p4;
    scene.triangles[2].p3 = p2;
    scene.triangles[2].normal = normalize(cross((p4-p3), (p2-p3)));
```

...

```
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve], test data and result and explanation why that result is wrong.

Comment: What's the problem with your code? does it crash or does it give a wrong result? What do you expect it to do and what does it really do?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `dot(triangle.normal,triangle.A - ray.origin))/dot(triangle.normal,ray.dir)`, focus on `triangle.A - ray.origin`

Comment: BTW your intersect function will blow up when the ray direction is perpendicular to triangle normal.

Comment: You have a type problem - `dot(triangle.normal, ray.origin)` is the dot product of a vector and a point. That does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood you try to check whether `ray` goes through `triangle`.
The very first error that I see is that `point`:

```
vec3 point = ray.origin + scalar * ray.dir;
```

has a meaningless definition. You calculate intersection of the `ray` with a parallel plane to the `triangle` that goes through the origin. Unless this plane for some miraculous reason coincides with the `triangle`'s plane, all forthcoming calculations with this `point` is devout of any meaning.

To fix this you need to define `scalar` like that:

```
float scalar = dot(triangle.normal,triangle.x) - dot(triangle.normal,ray.origin); 
scalar /= dot(triangle.normal,ray.dir);
```

where `triangle.x` is any point of the `triangle`.

After you fix this issue it will be possible to discuss whether other parts of your code make sense.

Also please provide more information about the details of the code, i.e., relevant pieces of the implementation.

---

Now about how to check whether ray intersects the triangle.
The method of intersecting ray with triangle's plane and then checking whether the point is inside the triangle in 2-dimansional setting - is not very good in terms of stability. So avoid it.

A more simple and direct method is to compute the difference vectors:

```
vec3 dvec1 = tringle.p1 - ray.origin;
vec3 dvec2 = tringle.p2 - ray.origin;
vec3 dvec3 = tringle.p3 - ray.origin;
```

and then check whether `ray.dir` can be expressed as a linear sum of `dvec1`, `dvec2`, and `dvec3` with positive coefficients. This can be achieved by computing the inverse of the matrix `mat3(dvec1,dvec2,dvec3)` and multiplying it by `ray.dir` (this way you obtain the coefficients that are needed to express `ray.dir` linear sum of `dvec1`, `dvec2`, and `dvec3`).

However, the matrix method isn't perfectly stable due divisions. This can be improved further by implementing a logically equivalent code just without divisions.

```
vec3 dvec12 = cross_product(dvec1, dvec2);
if(dot(dvec12,dvec3)*dot(dvec12,ray.dir) < 0.) return false;

vec3 dvec23 = cross_product(dvec2, dvec3);
if(dot(dvec23,dvec1)*dot(dvec23,ray.dir) < 0.) return false;

vec3 dvec31 = cross_product(dvec3, dvec1);
if(dot(dvec31,dvec2)*dot(dvec31,ray.dir) < 0.) return false;

return true;
```

In the first `if` we check if `ray.dir` is on the same half plane as `dvec3` with respect to the plane spanned by `{dvec1,dvec2}`. If it isn't then `ray` won't intersect the triangle.

Then we repeat this check for other vectors.

Comment: Ok I try that!Thanks!

Comment: @johanF In general I would write the function differently. 'mat3 M(triangle.x-ray.origin, triangle.y-ray.origin, triangle.z-ray.origin);' compute `vec3 rev = M.inverse()*ray.dir;` and then return true if all coordinates of `rev` are positive (on the second thought, this function might not be perfectly stable when the triangle is too small and be subjected to numerical errors).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to rewrite your code like this:

```
bool PointInOrOn( vec3 P1, vec3 P2, vec3 A, vec3 B )
{
    vec3 CP1 = cross( B - A, P1 - A )
    vec3 CP2 = cross( B - A, P2 - A )
    return step(0.0, dot( CP1, CP2 ));
}

float intersect(Ray ray, Triangle triangle)
{
    vec3 D = normalize(ray.dir);         // skip normalize, if ray.dir is normalized
    vec3 N = normalize(triangle.normal); // skip normalize, if triangle.normal is normalized

    float d = dot(triangle.p1 - ray.origin, N) / dot(D, N)
    vec3  X = ray.origin + D * d;

    float isIn = PointInOrOn( X, triangle.p1, triangle.p2, triangle.p3 ) *
                 PointInOrOn( X, triangle.p2, triangle.p3, triangle.p1 ) *
                 PointInOrOn( X, triangle.p3, triangle.p1, triangle.p2 );

    if ( isIn > 0.01 )
        return d;
    return -1.0;
}
```

See the following explanation.

---

**Intersection of a ray and a triangle primitive**

[image]

The ray is defined by a point `R0` and a normalized direction `D`.
The plane is defined by a triangle with the three points `PA`, `PB`, and `PC`.

The normal vector of the plane can be calculated by the cross product of 2 legs of the triangle:

```
N  =  normalize( cross(PC-PA, PB-PA)
```

The normal distance `n` of the point `R0` to the plane is:

```
n  =  | R0 - PA | * cos(alpha)  =  dot(PA - R0, N)
```

It follows that the distance `d` of the intersection point `X` to the origin of the ray R0 is:

```
d  =  n / cos(beta)  =  n / dot(D, N)
```

The intersection point `X` is:

```
X  =  R0 + D * d  =  R0 + D * dot(PA - R0, N) / dot(D, N)
```

---

To find out, if a point is inside a triangle, has to be tested, if the line from a corner point to the intersection point is between the to legs which are connect to the corner point. The triangle is defined by the points `A`, `B`, `C` and the point to be tested is `P`:

```
bool PointInOrOn( P1, P2, A, B )
{
    CP1 = cross( B - A, P1 - A )
    CP2 = cross( B - A, P2 - A )
    return dot( CP1, CP2 ) >= 0
}

bool PointInOrOnTriangle( P, A, B, C )
{
    return PointInOrOn( P, A, B, C ) &&
           PointInOrOn( P, B, C, A ) &&
           PointInOrOn( P, C, A, B )
}
```